# Material Point Method (MPM) applied to wave simulation problems?

Tags: computational-physics, simulations

MPM combines elements of both the finite element method (FEM) and the particle-based methods. It is particularly suitable for problems involving large deformations or fluid-solid interaction. Would you apply it (after proper editing) to wave propagation problems, where there is no mass transportation, but only energy transportation?

Comment: Why would you want to? I'm sure MPM can be used to solve any generic ODE/PDE, but if it's built/designed for a particular case (i.e., multi-phase interactions) why would you use it in a different case?

Comment: To avoid the challenge of building very complicated meshes

Comment: Aren't there mesh-generation schemes that do that auto-magically for you? I'm not sure why that would be a problem, even with complicated geometries. It might be better if you included a particular use case you're considering.